# CSS cross-browser conflict

Tags: css, browser

I'm Working on a web site (http://www.iwanttobesanta.com/about_us.html) more specific on About Us/Quem Somos page, that seens to be diferente depending on browser. When window < 500px the navbar (navBar.css) get out of the place in google chrome, but it's seens fine in firefox. Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: in chrome and in firefox i see the same at macos, navbar at top in both browsers.

Comment: Weired, but it's good news... i guess

Comment: remenber that the window has to be < 500px

Comment: The code is to extense to put here

Comment: @Miguel yes window with width less 500 show same result in both browsers

Comment: I really can't find the problem, just delete all cache, cookies etc... and nothing

Answer (score 0):

It is because of a media query for 500px width. (http://www.iwanttobesanta.com/css/stylesAboutUs.css)

the css for middleTextMob has margin top = 200px. This is causing the header to shift down.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem i want for middleTextMob to be margin 200px, that shouldn't mess with the navbar